# Adding more options to "Settings" ActionBarSherlock

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I have the following items to display on the ActionBar. They are :- Share and Settings.
Under Settings I need to show a drop down menu with two more options.

Here is my code:-

```
    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
  <!-- Search, should appear as action button -->
  <item android:id="@+id/action_share"
        android:icon="@drawable/share"
        android:title="Share"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
  <!-- Settings, should always be in the overflow -->
  <item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:title="Settings"
        android:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

How can I go ahead wit it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code for `subMenu` using `XML`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:id="@+id/action_share"
    android:icon="@drawable/share"
    android:title="Share"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

 <item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
      android:icon="@drawable/setting"
      android:title="@string/settings"
      android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText">
    <menu>
        <item android:id="@+id/option1"
              android:icon="@drawable/yourIcon"
              android:title="SubMenu1" />

        <item android:id="@+id/option2"
              android:icon="@drawable/yourIcon"
              android:title="SubMenu2" />
     </menu>
  </item>
</menu>
```

`JAVA` code for `Activity`

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.actionbar, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I added this snippet. However I cannot see any sub menus